# При запуске программы не работают встроенные функции

Tags: python, функции

Недавно начала заниматься по книге "Сам себе программист", при работе с разделом "Встроенные функции" возникла следующая задача: IDLE для Win-64 распознаёт `len`, `str` и прочее как функцию, но не выполняет их. В чём может быть причина неполадки?

[image: Скрин с происходящим на экране после запуска программы с встроеннойфункцией]^-^)

Comment: Он их выполнил и вернул результат, но вы же не написали, что сделать с результатом! Можно, например, отпечатать его: `print(len("Monty"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в shell окне вводите `len("blabla")` и вам выведет число, так же в файле `print(len("blabla"))`, перейти в директорию и запустить файл, командой `python scr.py`

Comment: Merser5, большое вам спасибо (^-^) После исправления в коде всё стало работать как должно)